# Appropriateness of Replacing "while" with "and" in sentence

Tags: word-usage

Sentence:

> "The senate adopted new rules to prevent representatives from serving on a committee ***while*** at the same time maintaining an interest in any company that conducts business that is affected by that committee's decisions."

Can "while" be replaced with and?

Comment: May I ask you to un-accept my answer? It is now meaningless; but an Accepted answer cannot be deleted.

Comment: You may use one star \* for italics, two stars \*\* for bold, or three stars \*\*\* for both.  Seven stars is probably pushing it :-)

Comment: @StoneyB  Sure, but you answered my question. the ill-formated question probably isn't helpful for others.

Comment: You can. IMO. Because you have *at the same time* phrase in the sentence.

Comment: After answering, I see that StoneyB had already answered this question correctly and sufficiently, and then deleted it.

Answer (score 3):

The original sentence:

> "The senate adopted new rules to prevent representatives from serving on a committee ***while at the same time*** maintaining an interest in any company that conducts business that is affected by that committee's decisions."

The sentence as your change is implied:

> "The senate adopted new rules to prevent representatives from serving on a committee ***and at the same time*** maintaining an interest in any company that conducts business that is affected by that committee's decisions."

I don't see any substantial change in the meaning of that sentence. That's probably because after *and*, the phrase *at the same time* takes care of keeping the meaning intact [This was also mentioned by StoneyB in his deleted answer].

However, it's worth to note that using the phrase *while at the same time* itself is redundant as mentioned [here](http://www.lawprose.org/blog/?p=2847), [here](http://grammarist.com/redundancies/) and [here](http://home.comcast.net/~garbl/stylemanual/vthruz.htm#while%20at%20the%20same%20time).